# How can I force Chrome to open index.html file while browsing a local directory?

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome

I am trying to implement an internal website on my company's shared hard drive.

Everything is going well except that I would like Chrome to open index.html file by default on root folder, exactly how it would do it on a remote web server. Any ideas, folks ?

What we do have as for now : [image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to run a webserver. By default, chrome will not serve any file, you have to open them on chrome properly. 
So, since you're using WordPress, I suggest you to run xampp, or anything similar. To run on internal local network you have to configure windows to allow incoming connections from your machine IP address